# Docker-compose: MySQL update breaks db

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I can't figure out a problem I have when watchtower is upgrading my wordpress stack.

The wordpress, mysql and phpmyadmin are correctly updated but the database is empty after every update.

The same problem happen when I use:

`docker-compose pull && docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d`

Here is my Docker compose file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/home/docker/mysite/database
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
       MYSQL_DATABASE: database
       MYSQL_USER: user
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     volumes:
       - ./html/:/var/www/html/ 
     ports:
       - "8002:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: user
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: database
       WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: ch_
       DISABLE_WP_CRON: "false"
   phpmyadmin:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
     container_name: chas_phpmyadmin
     restart: always
     environment:
        PMA_HOST: db
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
        UPLOAD_LIMIT: 300000000
     ports:
       - "8080:80"
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

I know I did something wrong I appreciate any help I can get !

Comment: Can you please describe the error you're getting? And can you properly indent the docker-compose code since it is indentation sensitive, so that can be what is causing whatever problem you're having.

Comment: Formatting must be better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration of mysql volume is bad. You defined `db_data:/home/docker/mysite/database`, but the value after `:` must correspond to the path into the `mysql:5.7` image that contains the DB folder, that is `var/lib/mysql`, instead of `/home/docker/mysite/database`.

The correct volumes configuration for mysql service is:

```
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
        - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
        - MYSQL_DATABASE: database
        - MYSQL_USER: user
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
```

You can find more detail on [MySQL page of Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) in **Where to Store Data** section.